# How can I use a java string image object in a html img tag - Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, html, image

I am currently generating a javascript image from a base64 string.
I am doing something like this

```
function generateHTML() 
{
  var image = new Image();
  var src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + picString;
  image.src = src;
  ......
}
```

Now I know i can do something like this

```
document.body.appendChild(image);
```

but that is not what I want. In my javascript function I am returning back an html string. My question is if it is possible for me to use the javascript image with a html statement like this

```
<img src=image alt="Mountain View" style="width:304px;height:228px;">
```

Comment: You could just do what you currently are doing and then use `image.outerHTML` to get the html string that makes up the image. Or you can just string concatenation, eg `...src="'+dataURLVariable+'"...`

Comment: yes @PatrickEvans that did the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to get the html string of an element and not looking to append it to the current document, use [outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) on the Image instance you created.

```
function generateHTML() {
  var image = new Image();
  var src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + picString;
  image.src = src;
  return image.outerHTML;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You mean like this, where it uses the img id to append the src?

```js
function generateHTML() {
  var picString = "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==";
  var image = new Image();
  var src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + picString;
  document.getElementById('img').src = src;
}

generateHTML();
```

```html
<img id="img" alt="Mountain View" title="Red Dot" />
```

Comment: this looks good but in my document I dont have an image element.so `document.getElementById('img').src` that will fail